# variable array size at arduino

Tags: arrays, variables, size, arduino

I have an SD card which I filled with 15 mp3 tracks and a text file that has 15 words and 15 tracks names. My question is regarding initializing the following

```
char* words[ ]
char* tracks [ ]
```

When I initialize them as `[100]` and `[100]`, the listing of the dB doesn't work as I currently only have 15 tracks and words. I want code to have the ability to place 999.

So my question is: can I make both them variable arrays and how?

I tried leaving between the brackets empty and several other methods but they didn't work.
So I wondering if anyone here have any other suggestions.

Comment: Use dynamic memory allocations, `malloc` and then `realloc`?

Comment: I tried using malloc but it didn't work, however will try to use realloc, thanks for your fast reply :D

Comment: Note `char*words[]` is an array of pointers! You will need buffer for string data also `char[][]`. As this is all dynamic, you better not use static arrays, but use some `new` keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino version of C/C++ has a great feature - VLA (variable length array, from C99)
So, just use:

```
void process(int n)
{
    // Set up a buffer of n characters
    char b[n];
    // do the work
}
```

See: http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-cwhy-variable-length-arrays/184401444

You need array of arrays? No problem (I hope). Pseudocode:

```
char* words[N]; // N - words
char word1[M] // M - word length
char word2[O] // O - second word length

words[0] = word1;
words[1] = word2;
```

Many answers suggest to use dynamic memory allocation - it works, but main drawback of such method - memory fragmentation. But remember - dynamic memory allocation is only method to return arrays from functions!

P.S. I can't verify code with compiler at the moment - please give me feedback if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Arduino code is compiled as C++; you can use the `new char[size]` and `delete[]` operators.

Comment: I tried what still i didnt get anything but when i tried using:  
//words = (char** )calloc(track_size++,sizeof(char*));
//tracks = (char** )calloc(track_size++,sizeof(char*));
with delete [];
it only outputs the last word and last track, i dont understand why??